# UnicodeEncodeError when using scipy.io.savemat

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have a dateframe contain Chinese character like this:[image]

I want to save as `.mat` file using

```
datanew = r'data/newmat.mat'
scio.savemat(datanew,{'date':df})
```

But got error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried add code `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`in the first line and `import sys
default_encoding = 'utf-8'`. But didn't work.

Comment: Have you used any other encoding i.e. `latin-1`, `ISO-5589-1` etc

Comment: Python and `numpy` work fine with `unicode`, I'm sure that MATLAB, at least in older `.mat` format does.  Another thing to watch for - the `loadmat/savemat` pair work with `numpy` arrays, and are best with numeric ones.  Don't try to write a pandas dataframe directly.  `savemat` has to write the array in a MATLAB compatible format - matrices, cell, and struct.  It doesn't not have a direct dataframe translation.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that MATLAB and this older `.mat` format might not work with `unicode`.   MATLAB is a specialized language that's been around for a long time.  It certainly didn't start with `unicode`. Python is a general purpose language, with more incentive to handle international texts.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. Convert dataframe to np.array before save as .mat is work. But the .mat file is four times size than .csv file and I guess the reason is Chinese character.